# How to extract the N minimum points and N maximum points (ignoring repeating points in an array) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a sorted array of points like

```
x=[1 1 1 2 2 4 4 5 6 ......7 8 8 9 9]
```

I want to have an array containing 3 elements with minimum elements and 3 with maximum elements of this array (ignoring the same elements)

The desired results for the above would be

```
ans=[1 2 4 7 8 9]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the function [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html):

```
uniqueValues = unique(x);  %# Get the unique values of x
minmaxValues = uniqueValues([1:3 end-2:end]);  %# Get the 3 smallest and largest
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the documentation for `unique`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html

Comment: Also worth noting you don't need a sorted array to use unique, unique also sorts

Comment: how to get unique values w.r.t 1st row.if i have x=[1 1 1 2 2 4 4 5 6 7 8 8 9 9;3 4 5 4 1 5 6 7 7 8 0 2 1 3]   than how to get this  ans=[1 2 4 7 8 9;3 4 5 8 0 2]

Comment: @chee: The second row of ans makes no sense. Why would you expect to get that? What are you trying to do?

Comment: look if i have 2 dimension or 3 dimensions of a point like x y and z.than in this case i need to do like that.if i take a unique point from 1st row than i ill have to take its corresponding point from 2nd row.

Comment: @chee: To do that, you can use the second output from UNIQUE. For example: [y,i] = unique(x(1,:)); ans = x(:,i);

Comment: this is not taking corresponding points it gives ans like ans = [1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9; 5 1 6 7 7 8 2 3]

Comment: @chee: It is taking corresponding points. By default, UNIQUE will find the *last* occurrence of a number, so the last occurrence of 1 is in column 3, corresponding to a 5 in the second row. If you instead want the *first* occurrence, do this: `[y,i] = unique(x(1,:),'first'); ans = x(:,i([1:3 end-2:end]));`. This should give you `ans = [1 2 4 7 8 9; 3 4 5 8 0 1];`.

Comment: ok now if i want to do this w.r.t 2nd row.i mean i get unique values from 2nd row with their corresponding values from 1st row.like i want ans like: x=[3 4 5 4 1 5 6 7 7 8 0 2 1 3;1 1 1 2 2 4 4 5 6 7 8 8 9 9]  ans=[3 4 5 8 0 1;1 2 4 7 8 9] than????

Comment: @chee: Have you tried solving it yourself? I think that it should be really easy to figure out how to do what you want by making a small change to the code I gave you. Look closely at the first argument I pass to UNIQUE: `x(1,:)`.

Answer (score 3):

A bit less elegant, but takes advantage of sorted input, so much faster.

```
i = find(diff(x)~=0);
ans = x([i([1:3 end-1:end]) end]);
```

Comment: +1, although the `~=0` is actually not necessary, since [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) will find the indices of all non-zero elements.